# Teamcity Build won't run until Build Agents is configured with Docker?

Tags: docker, build, continuous-integration, teamcity

I created a new build for my Teamcity pipeline. For the first time I use then Docker buildstep. After I setup everything I realized the build agent does not seem to be ready for it.

[image]

I understand that my agent does not seem to be ready for building with docker **but** nobody is actually telling me how you can do that. I read the official guides but no word about how to actually install docker into my agent (if that's the way to solve the problem).

Can someone tell me what I have to do to get it to work?

**EDIT**

@Senior Pomidor helped me to get one step closer. I added his first example to the docker run command

```
docker run -it -e SERVER_URL="<url to TeamCity server>"  \
    --privileged -e DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start \    
    jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

After doing so I got rid of the mentioned messages in the screenshot. My Agents configuration now has the following:

```
docker.server.osType     linux
docker.server.version    18.06.1
docker.version   18.06.1
```

**But** still Teamcity is complaining with this message:

[image]

Which kinda leaves me clueless again.

**Final Solution**:
The upcoming EDIT2 issue could be resolved by just restarting the teamcity server instance. The agent was actually able to run the build but teamcity was not able to realise that without a reboot.

**EDIT2**

Request Information:

My CI Server OS:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
```

Running Container:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                       COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
0f8e0b04d6a6        jetbrains/teamcity-agent    "/run-services.sh"   19 hours ago        Up 19 hours         9090/tcp               teamcity-agent
20964c22b2d9        jetbrains/teamcity-server   "/run-services.sh"   37 hours ago        Up 37 hours         0.0.0.0:80->8111/tcp   teamcity-server-instance
```

Container run by:

```
## Server
docker run -dit --name teamcity-server-instance  -v /data/teamcity:/data/teamcity_server/datadir -v /var/log/teamcity:/opt/teamcity/logs  -p 80:8111 jetbrains/teamcity-server

## Agent
docker run -itd --name teamcity-agent -e SERVER_URL="XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80"  --privileged -e DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start -v /etc/teamcity/agent/conf:/data/teamcity_agent/conf jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

Build Step Information:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: because agent launched without docker. How you run your agent? does your agent run as a Docker container?

Comment: Yes it does run as a container. I wonder how I can install Docker into it. Just `exec` into the container and apt-get docker or what?

Comment: could you please add information of your build configuration and servers where TA runs? I think your configuration need the Windows server

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Added infos about the server and about ci configurations

Comment: could you please open your agent -> Agent Parameters -> Configuration Parameters -> copy value `docker.server.osType` and send here?

Comment: I kinda felt what you about to tell me. This is what I found via HTML Debugger: `&nbsp;linux`. There is a whitespace! Or doesn't that affect anything?

Comment: I think your agent requirement contains '' linux" not `"linux"`. 
I want to say the requirements contains space before or after `linux`. can you click edit- > cleat -> fill  start over, and check ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191738/discussion-between-xetra11-and-senior-pomidor).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

TC restricted the configuration because of TA doesn't start Docker daemon.

You should pass  `-e DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start`  for automatically staring the docker daemon in the container. Also, docker daemon needs the docker socket.  In a Linux container, if you need a Docker daemon available inside your builds, you have two options:

- `--privileged`  flag.  New Docker daemon running within your container
- `-v docker_volumes:/var/lib/docker` Docker from the host (in this case you will benefit from the caches shared between the host and all your containers but there is a security concern: your build may actually harm your host Docker, so use it at your own risk)

In a Linux container, if you need a Docker daemon available inside your builds, you have two options:

1. Docker from the host (in this case you will benefit from the caches shared between the host and all your containers but there is a security concern: your build may actually harm your host Docker, so use it at your own risk)

examples

```
docker run -it -e SERVER_URL="<url to TeamCity server>"  \
    --privileged -e DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start \    
    jetbrains/teamcity-agent 

docker run -it -e SERVER_URL="<url to TeamCity server>"  \
    -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock  \
    jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

UPD

`docker.server.osType` required because in the build step was sets `linux`

Comment: That really helped but still there is something not working please check my edit in the post

Answer (score 5):

What worked for me was changing permissions on the agent container for `/var/run/docker.sock`

Run a shell inside the container:
`docker exec -u 0 -it <CONTAINER_ID> bash`

Change permissions of the docker socket:
`chmod 666 /var/run/docker.sock`

Verify the docker container use the socket:
`docker version`

Comment: Thank you for helping me, I was confused which already adding docker sock file to volume
'/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock'
but still not loaded, I never though it was permission issue

Thanks again!