# How can I add the `--privileged` flag of Docker to a Kubernetes pod spec container YAML definition

Tags: docker, kubernetes

In this question: [Teamcity Build won't run until Build Agents is configured with Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631068/teamcity-build-wont-run-until-build-agents-is-configured-with-docker)

I had a problem with the teamcity-agent (Teamcity is a build server) deployment. These agents are the build runners and they come as their own pods. So back the days when I was just using Docker without K8s I used this command to run the container:

```
docker run -it -e SERVER_URL="<url to TeamCity server>"  \
    --privileged -e DOCKER_IN_DOCKER=start \    
    jetbrains/teamcity-agent
```

So adding those environement vars to the K8s container definition wasn't that hard. I just had to define this `spec` part:

```
spec:
  containers:
    - name: teamcity-agent
      image: jetbrains/teamcity-agent:latest
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8111
      env:
        - name: SERVER_URL
          value: 10.0.2.205:8111
        - name: DOCKER_IN_DOCKER
          value: start
```

So now I want to have the `--privileged` flag as well. I found and article here [link to guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/security-context/) which I did not really understood. I added

```
securityContext:
  allowPrivilegeEscalation: false // also tried 'true'
```

but it did not worked with that.

Can someone point out where to look at?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may use it like this

```
securityContext:
  privileged: true
```

see [this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/pod-security-policy/)